# Customization of ASCX user controls

Tags: ascx

We have a little situation thats kinda got out of hand latly.
Our web application is built upon several ASCX user controls. All of them
is available to customize (pointing to another ASCX-path). What we do
when we customize is to make a copy of the source ASCX and make some
changes.

Now the problem, when there have been much commits to the source ASCX the
customzied copy is way behind the source ASCX and much work has to be done
manually to get them in par.

We have a winforms application that have similar technique for customizing
but its no problem there because of the degsin inheritance of usercontrols.

Anyone know a better way to customize web controls that dont make so much
problems when rebuilding?

Answer (score 1):

- Use inheritance there, too.
- Dont use ascx but real controls and a skinning framework.
- Dump user controls, go MVC. Then the views are not containing any significant logic, so the maintenance of customized stuff is easier.

Comment: When you say "Use inheritance there, too." what exactly do you mean? To inherit my cusom ascx from the source one? But then how can I for example reposition a table or such that resides in the source ascx?